# Can't translate a line

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, csv

I'd like to translate a line in checkout > payment information but I dont' find the CSV file. I tried to add the translation on mage_sales.csv but it didn't work.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in `Mage_Checkout.csv` or `Mage_Payment.csv` file

Or you can add it in your theme locale translate file as well

For example

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/locale/your_Locale/translate.csv
```

Comment: I tried all these CSV files but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Not all lines can be translated, check the source code to see if it's plain text or wrapped like this:

`<?php echo $this->__('YOUR TEXT GOES HERE') ?>`

Plain text can't be translated automatically through Magento, you have to wrap the text like above for the translation to work.